# Swift loop through array of dictionaries

Tags: loops, swift, dictionary

Why am I getting this error when looping through an array of dictionaries ?

```
import UIKit

let tableView = UITableView()

func meh() {
    let product = buildCells()
    for (identifier, nib) in product {
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}

func buildCells() -> [[String: UINib]] {
    var collector = [[String: UINib]]()
    let identifier = "identifier"
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    let asdf = [identifier: nib];
    collector.append(asdf)
    return collector
}
```

The `forin` loop in the `meh()` method produces the following error:

> 'Dictionary' is not convertible to '([[String : UINib]], [[String : UINib]])'

Comment: While the screenshot is nice, please post the source code and the error message as plain text in the question so it cooperates with Google (and suggests to you questions that you might be duplicating when writing your question).  Plus, its actually copy&pastable, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't iterate through the keys and values of an array of dictionaries.  We can iterate through the dictionaries though.  And for each dictionary, we can iterate through its keys and values:

```
let product = buildCells()
for dict in product {
    for (identifier, nib) in dict {
        tableview.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}
```

But I think the problem is actually more likely the nonsense going on in `buildCells()`.  Why are you returning an array of dictionaries?  Do you plan to have duplicate keys?  I don't think the tableview will let you register multiple nibs for the same identifier.

Why don't we just return a dictionary?

```
func buildCells() -> [String: UINib] {
    var dict = [String: UINib]()
    dict["identifier"] = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    // rinse & repeat for all of your other ID/nib combos with no duplicate IDs
    return dict
}
```

Now we can iterate over the key/value pairs in the dictionary without the outer loop:

```
for (identifier, nib) in dict {
    tableview.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
}
```

Comment: ...because i was coding late last night and this approach seemed to make all of the sense in the world.